# Adding std::thread to a preexisting project

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake

I'm working off of a sample c++ that I was given, and I'm trying to add threading to the program.

If anywhere in the program I add the following:

```
#include <thread>

void someFunction () {
    std::thread t([]() {std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; });
}
```

It fails to compile with the error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thread(48): error C3083: 'std': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
1>  C:\Users\Dennis Jeong\Documents\Stanford\CS148\cs148-raytracer\common\RayTracer.cpp(20): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<RayTracer::Run::<lambda_d2fd5ec539e104442fc3c5987873ac7f>,,void>(_Fn &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=RayTracer::Run::<lambda_d2fd5ec539e104442fc3c5987873ac7f>
1>          ]
```

However, if I create a new c++ project in visual studio, this works.

Where could the error possibly be?

If it is helpful, the cmake file is here:
https://gist.github.com/w0nche0l/aef2a112b596f489705441f429e725b5

EDIT: additionally, I'm sure that it is not the lambda syntax that is causing this error, because I can create and run lambdas without threads fine.

Comment: Is the `#include <thread>` at the top of a source module, or contained within another namespace?

Comment: what are the project options? are you sure you're running `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @Ap31: That will be it - the "if I create a new C++ project it works" is a dead give away.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` maybe.

Comment: @Ap31 Its using visual studio; other c++11 features work and i can run an empty thread that doesn't take a lambda

Comment: @Velkan iostream is also included.